# iOS save CIImage to Camera Roll

Tags: ios, image-processing, core-image

I'm running several CoreImage filters on an image from device's camera, and have run into unexpected troubles saving the result to Camera Roll. The result of my image manipulations is a `CIImage` and the data types I can save into ALAssetsLibrary are either `CGImageRef` or `NSData` (via `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:` and `writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:` respectively).

Seems like a trivial task, but I cannot find a working way to convert my `CIImage` to a usable data type that can be written to the photo library (with JPEG compression).

Edit: I would like to save image metadata as well, so that rules out some of the simple UIImage saving techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
-(void)storeImage:(CIImage*)_image
  CGImageRef cgImg = [context createCGImage:_image fromRect:[_image extent]];
  ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
  [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:cgImg 
                               metadata:[_image properties] 
                        completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {
                          CGImageRelease(cgImg);
                        }];
```

Comment: Like many other things, ALAssetsLibrary is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, create a UIImage object and use `initWithCIImage:`. You can then pass the new UIImage to `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum()`.

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCIImage:myCIImage];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: That kind of works, but on a very basic level - this method does not support saving image metadata, unlike `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock` and its NSData based sibling.

Comment: I'm trying this exact method in iOS 9 and it isn't working.

Comment: also this requires much more memory if images are very large